# How to send a callback from Android to Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, kotlin

I am trying to call an Android native function "refreshPages" from JS function "refreshPagesWithIds" which passes an array of strings to native.

```
id: ["1","2"];
refreshPagesWithIds(id) {
  return Android.refreshPages(id);
}
```

The Android native function "refreshPages" internally calls a method "someFunction" which takes id array as argument and returns a Promise after refreshing the pages.

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void refreshPages(String[] ids) {
        StorageModule.someFunction(ids, null);
    }
```

someFunction looks like:

```
@JvmStatic
    fun someFunction(pageIds: ReadableArray, promise: Promise? = null) {
        val storagePromise = StoragePromise(promise, storageModules.size)
        storageModules.forEach { module -> module.refreshPagesWithIds(pageIds, storagePromise) }
    }
```

How can I return a value when the Promise from refreshPages function(in native) gets settled to Javascript?
I am unable to understand the implementation for **public void refreshPages(String[] ids)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A java promise is different than a javascript promise, the only thing related between them is the name. You can not return a promise from java to javascript, even if syntax enables that you will be sending a serialised cloned object which has no relation to the one in java - the one in java might be completed, but you wont know about that in javascript.

What you could do is in javascript something like this

```
arePagesRefereshed: true
id: ["1","2"];
refreshPagesWithIds(id) {
  // this seems to be sitting in an object, so i am just assuming that this refers to the object, but you get the point
  this.arePagesRefereshed = false
  return Android.refreshPages(id);
},
markPagesAsRefereshed: () => {
  this.arePagesRefereshed = true

}
```

and then in Java

```
@JvmStatic
    fun someFunction(pageIds: ReadableArray, promise: Promise? = null) {
        val storagePromise = StoragePromise(promise, storageModules.size)
        storageModules.forEach { module -> module.refreshPagesWithIds(pageIds, storagePromise) }
    // after all promises are completed call markPagesAsRefereshed in javascript
    }
```

Comment: When promise in Android gets resolved, how can I send value to JS?

Comment: @AashnaNarula Well call a javascript function with that value, for example call markPagesAsRefereshed(resolvedValue)